# Query by Example Spring Data - In Clause?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, query-by-example

As per Spring Docs, I can write exact matching only for QBE.
I need exact matching only but among a set of values (IN clause of query).

e.g.

```
Person p = new Person();
p.setId(); // need to match among set of ids.
Example.of(p);
```

Is this somehow achievable with QBE or am I totally down the wrong path?

Something like :

```
Page<S> findByIdIn(List<Integer> ids, Example<S> e, Pageable p)
```

best of both worlds?

What I really need, dynamic query based on multiple fields (in possible combinations, say id in (1,2,4), status=open, appointmentDate < today) 
along with pagination and sorting.
Is specification the only way to go apart from native query?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I need exact matching only but among a set of values (IN clause of query).

So you need something other than exact matching. You can't possibly store a set of IDs in the ID property of your Person. QBE is clearly not the right tool for the job.

You can use Specifications, the Criteria API directly, QueryDSL, a dynamically composed JPQL query, or whatever other solution, but not QBE.

Comment: was hoping for something like:
Page<S> findByIdIn(List<Integer> ids, Example<S> e, Pageable p)

Comment: [Spring Data documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#query-by-example.matchers) - non string values are not allowed for matching (only exact matching)

Comment: I'll be writing specifications then.

Comment: You can transform an Example into a Predicate that you can then combine with other predicates using https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/convert/QueryByExamplePredicateBuilder.html